# Date Time field machine name/view mode for theming using paragraphs

Tags: views, 8, theming, nodes, datetime

I am using Drupal 8 core DateTime Range module and Date module in core to list date start and end date.

I have set various criteria and allowed content editors to set date/time under certain ranges with paragraphs module for events.

1. Event only has date.
   Created a date field using paragraphs module.
2. Event has date with start and end time.
   Created a date field and datetime range field with only time ranges using paragraphs module.
3. Event has start and end date.
   Created a datetime range fields using paragraphs with date ranges using paragraphs m.
4. Event has start and end date with time.
   Created two datetime field one with date ranges and another with time ranges using paragraphs.

Now for theming I need to target each field separately as each field represents different format and style. However while using paragraphs inside node and adding any one of datetime field to node using paragraphs does not allow me to determine which field it is or what view mode that datetime field is using.

This makes it difficult to theme those fields individually/seperately.

Also, while using views pages and rendering those datetime field on a pager based page view, same, it does not show what machine name/view mode its using for paragraphs.

I implemented *hook_theme_suggestions_time_alter* function to determine the machine name and view mode, but no information was available for said field.

I would like to each part of field in datetime field separately and differently while rendering using views and differently while rendering in full view mode of node.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to Debug this is to enable twig debug
open up or create sites/default/services.yml

change

```
 http.response.debug_cacheability_headers: true
 twig.config: 
   auto_reload: true
   cache: true
   debug: true
```

once done run drush cr or clear your cache

then go to the page with the paragraphs on them and inspect the element in chrome 
you will see ... 
some thing like

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
  * field--paragraph--field-range--event.html.twig
  * field--paragraph--field-range.html.twig
  * field--paragraph--event.html.twig
  * field--field-range.html.twig
  * field--daterange.html.twig
  x field.html.twig
  -->
```

then theme the new field templates to your liking

Comment: These are paragraph fields templates that I am getting, however what I want to target is time field templates not paragraphs field. I have already enabled debug mode and set up view mode for paragraphs. I want to theme those time fields with individual designs for each time field type defined within paragraphs.

Comment: field--paragraph--field-range--event.html.twig allows to theme a group of fields defined within a particular type. I would like to target the time.html.twig within that paragraph type and theme those 4 type of structure so as to display in node full view page and views page.

Comment: I was expecting view mode for time field. I guess its not possible. I see view mode for paragraphs though.